# Get code block to copy to clipboard in react

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working on a project website for my own use and it has a lot of code examples such as:

```
<code>mycommand -e {this.state.target}</code>
```

I would like a copy box next to it, such as those used on the bootstrap documentation.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/code/

I found a library that does copy-to-clipboard:

```
<code>mycommand -e {this.state.target}</code>
<CopyToClipboard text="Hello!">
      <button>Copy to clipboard with button</button>
</CopyToClipboard>
```

But I am struggling to find a good example on copying the code out of the above code block.

Any suggestions for a neat way of doing this as I have hundreds of code examples? I don't really want to type the code twice or store it as a variable because it becomes slower/harder to manage.

So in the above example, I want it to copy:

```
mycommand -e hi.zip
```

Comment: I think you can use ref to get the reference to the dom element and get the innerHtml or innerText using that ref.

Comment: So copy the text and use the clipboard api and write to it. You should be able to know what the text is either in the JavaScript code or by reading it with textContent

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of solving it.

```
    <code> mycommand -e {this.state.target} </code>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(
          document.querySelector("code").textContent
        );
      }}
    >
      Copy to clipboard with button
    </button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).